# Finding the number of 16-digit hexadecimal numbers with atleast one 0,1 and A

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations, probability, combinatorics

I was trying to solve the Project Euler problem 162- 
https://projecteuler.net/problem=162

> In the hexadecimal number system numbers are represented using 16
>   different digits:
>
> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F
>
> The hexadecimal number AF when written in the decimal number system
>   equals 10x16+15=175.
>
> In the 3-digit hexadecimal numbers 10A, 1A0, A10, and A01 the digits
>   0,1 and A are all present.
>
> Like numbers written in base ten we write hexadecimal numbers without
>   leading zeroes.
>
> How many hexadecimal numbers containing at most sixteen hexadecimal
>   digits exist with all of the digits 0,1, and A present at least once?
>   Give your answer as a hexadecimal number.

It looked like an easy problem to do with a help of a little code :

```
import math

def ncr(n,r):
    return math.factorial(n)//math.factorial(r)//math.factorial(n-r)

sum =0
n=16
for x in range(1,n):
    for y in range(1,n):
        for z in range(1,n):
            if(x+y+z <= n):
                s = x+y+z
                t = ncr(n,s)*ncr(s,x)*ncr(y+z,y)*pow(13,n-s)
                sum += t

for x in range (1,n-1):
    for y in range (1,n-1):
        if(x+y<=n-1):
            s = x+y
            t = ncr(n-1,s)*ncr(s,x)*pow(14,n-1-s)
            sum -= t

print(sum)
```

My logic -

Lets say there are x 0's, y 1's and z A's in the number, now, for every possible case where x+y+z is less than or equal to 16, I define s = x+y+z

Now I choose **s** places from the total **16** digits,

then **x** places from those **s** places,

then **y** places from the **y+z** remaining places,

and then, finally, the remaining **16-s** places can be filled by any other digit other than 0,1,A , so **13^(16-s)**

Now since these case involve 0 being present at the first position, I add a second loop to subtract all the values which have 0 the first position and atleast one 1 and A. I used the same logic for that too.

Now i dont know if I am making a HUGE logical mistake or just a small silly one, but am not really able to figure out why am I not getting the correct answer.

I dont need the correct answer or the correct way to solve this, just want to know what is wrong with this logic / code, any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks

P.S. - This is my first question here, Do tell if something was wrong with the way of asking the question.

Comment: Hint: have a look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle, for example to get how many numbers have at least one '1' take all numbers and subtract the numbers without '1'. Both counts are very easy to determine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I see in your code is that you consider only 16 digit numbers while the problem asks for "containing at most sixteen hexadecimal digits".

Comment: i dont think that could be the problem, you see, x is the number of 0's there right?
So there would be numbers like 0000000000001A1A etc

Comment: But a zero at the beginning does not count as being present. Therefore the example 0000000000001A1A is not a valid number.

Comment: Wait...sorry...i believe you are correct, my bad...I guess am just extremely confused huh? :P
Thanks a lot...I got the mistake in the code.. :D